# Material slot is reversed in unity when importing .blend file?

Tags: unity, blender, materials

I'm importing .blend file into unity. The file contains 9 separate objects. Now all objects have the same 2 materials assigned. When importing in unity one object's material slot is reversed. But in blender I set the slots correctly.

*Slot in blender*
[image: Blender img]

*Slot in unity*
[image: Unity img]

This is only happening for one object (*Curve.076*).
This is important for me as I am assigning the material from code to each slot.
Here's the .blend file if you want to look at it. [Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d189wpcw2xqrcz9/jigsaw.blend?dl=1)

**New Update:**

Okay so playing with the object for some time I found that the problem is with only related to one face.
In the picture below see the white face between blue faces, if leave the face like this than the slot in unity is
not reversing. But if I assign the face to the *inside.004* material than the slots are reversing.
I tried delete the face and again filling the area. But same result. I have to make the face same material as the upper
part to not get the problem, which I don't want. Only work arround I can use currently is that extruding the face little
forward and assinging the material to it, which is not very neat. I might be missing something as I am not very good at
blender. 
[image: new info]

*Unity 2018.3.4f1*

*Blender 2.79b*

Comment: Does the object actually get rendered wrong (those polygons which are supposed to use one material use the other one) or is this just a logical problem with the order of the material slots in the inspector?

Comment: Yes, the object is rendered wrong.